# Как правильно декларировать асинхронный метод с параметрами

Tags: c#, generics, repository, async-await

*Имеется класс:*

```
public class Store
{
    //синхронный метод
    public ICollection<T> GetAll<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
    {
        using(var c = new Context())
        {
            return c.Get<T>(include);
        }
    }

    //асинхронный метод
    public async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
    {
        return await Task<ICollection<T>>.Factory.StartNew(GetAll<T>);
    }
}
```

Как передать аргумент асинхронного метода `GetAllAsync<T>()` в метод `GetAll<T>()`, который будет вызываться в  `Task`?

Comment: Два замечания: 1) В методе `GetAllAsync` не нужен `await` и сам метод можно не помечать как 'async' (небольшая оптимизация), 2) Метод `GetAllAsync` нарушает TAP: публичные API должны содержать только "настоящие" (I/O-bound) методы, асинхронные обертки для синхронных методов не рекомендуются -- клиенту предоставляется синхронный метод, а дальше он сам решает, как его запускать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через замыкание:

```
return await Task<ICollection<T>>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAll(include));
```

PS

Но лучше так не делайте. Если вы используете Entity Framework 6 - то там есть специальные методы для асинхронного получения результата без создания дополнительного потока.

Если отбросить дополнительные слои, должно получиться как-то так:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

// ...

public async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    using(var c = new ВашDbContext())
    {
        IQueryable<T> q = c.Set<T>();
        foreach (var expr in includes)
          q = q.Include(expr);
        return await q.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пожалуй, мне это подходит. А что это за понятие такое - "замыкание" (для меня - новое)? Не поделитесь ли ссылочкой, где можно почитать?

Comment: @klutch1991 в любом учебнике или гугле. Называется по разному - "замыкание", "лябмда", "анонимная функция". Да вы не могли пропустить этот синтаксис, без него не передать параметра в `GetAll` / `GetAllAsync`.

Comment: ну, с лямбдами/анонимными методами я-то знаком, конечно :) Просто первый раз слышу, что это ещё называют замыканием. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь)